# matplotlib prune tick labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, label

I am using GridSpec to plot two plots one below the other without a gap in between with

```
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(3, 1)
gs.update(hspace=0., wspace=0.)
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0:2, 0])
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[2, 0], sharex=ax1)
```

which works fine. However, I want to get rid of each subplot's top and bottom tick label.
For that I use

```
nbins = len(ax1.get_yticklabels())
ax1.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(nbins=nbins, prune='both'))
nbins = len(ax2.get_yticklabels())
ax2.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(nbins=nbins, prune='both'))
```

which in many cases works fine. In some plots, however, one or more of the 4 labels to prune are still there. I looked at e.g. `ax1.get_ylim()` and noticed that instead of for example the upper limit being `10` (as it is shown in the plot itself), it is actually `10.000000000000002`, which I suspect is the reason why it is not pruned. How does that happen and how can I get rid of that?

Here is an example: Note that in the figure the y axis is inverted and no label is pruned, altough it should be. Also note that for some reason the lowest y-label is set to a negative position, which I don't see. The y-tick positions are shown in in axis coordinates in the text within the plots. In the image below, the label at 10.6 should not be there!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
import numpy as np

x1 = 1
y1 = 10.53839
err1 = 0.00865
x2 = 2
y2 = 9.43045
err2 = 0.00658

plt.clf()
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(3, 1)
gs.update(hspace=0., wspace=0.)
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0:2, 0])

ax1.errorbar(x1, y1, yerr=err1)
ax1.errorbar(x2, y2, yerr=err2)

ax1.invert_yaxis()

plt.setp(ax1.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)  # Remove x-labels between the plots
plt.xlim(0, 3)

ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[2, 0], sharex=ax1)

nbins = len(ax1.get_yticklabels())
ax1.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(nbins=8, prune='both'))
nbins = len(ax2.get_yticklabels())
ax2.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(nbins=6, prune='both'))

plt.savefig('prune.png')
plt.close()
```

[image: prune]

Comment: From your question, it sounds like you want to have the same x-axis, and so no tick labels at all fro that one, covered in the answer below, and then you just want to prune lower and upper, for the upper and lower graphs, respectively. Is that an accurate interpretation?

Comment: Exactly, the x axis is just fine. I want to set the number of y-ticks (in the example above `nbins`,) and from that I want to prune the upper and lower value, if it is locate at the (lower or upper) end of the axis.

Comment: I can not reproduce the error. With the code you provided (including the line in my answer below) everything works as it should for me. Could you provide an example that shows the problem?

Comment: Yes, I will try to make a minimal example and get back to you.

Comment: I see the problem now. However, your example is still very large. Could you try to remove everything that is irrelevant to the question?

Comment: I am having the same problem when using ```mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.Grid``` and it looks like a bug to me. You want to report it to the matplotlib team or shall I do it?

Comment: Please do, good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be, that you are looking at the left most label on the x axis of the upper plot? If so, this should do the trick:

```
ax1.set_xticklabels([])
```

**EDIT**: If you use `sharex`, you have to use this, otherwise the tick labels are removed on both axes.

```
plt.setp(ax1.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
```

Comment: No, I don't use any x labels between the two plots, hence `hspace=0.` what prune is supposed to do is to prune the highest and lowest tick label, if it is located at either end of the y-axis. But in many cases it just doesn't do that.

Comment: From your code it was not clear, that you already removed the x tick labels.

Comment: Yes, I see, sorry about that. However, for the pruning problem the x axis is unimportant.

Comment: Thanks, I know, that is what I've been using, of course. I edited the question to include an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this:

```
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker

ax2.yaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.MaxNLocator(nbins=7, prune='upper'))
```

I found the above command only works for the y-axis.

Does someone know how to set up the maximum limits of x-axis tickers' number?