# matplotlib get axis-relative tick positions

Tags: python, matplotlib, axes

I know that I can get the positions of my y-ticks by `ax.get_yticks()` (btw., is that the best/correct way to get them?). But I need the tick positions relative to the axis limits (i.e., between 0 and 1). What is the best way to get that? I tried `ax.get_yticks(transform=ax.transAxes)`, which does not work.

Comment: I do not understand your question at all

Comment: @tcaswell I think he wants to get the tick positions in Axes coordinates.

Comment: _why_ do you want this?  I have a suspicion that you are doing something the very hard way ;)

Comment: Because [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27910125/1812066) does not work and I have to get rid of overlapping labels while having no gap between the plots.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This transformation can be easily done by hand:

```
y_min, y_max = ax.get_ylim()
ticks = [(tick - y_min)/(y_max - y_min) for tick in ax.get_yticks()]
```

**UPDATE**

To get it working with log scales, we need to employ [`matplotlib.transforms`](http://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html). But transforms can only work with `(x,y)` points, so we need first to complement y-ticks with some x coordinates (for example, zeros):

```
crd = np.vstack((np.zeros_like(ax.get_yticks()), ax.get_yticks())).T
```

Then we can transform data coodinates to display and then to axes and take `y` column of it:

```
ticks = ax.transAxes.inverted().transform(ax.transData.transform(crd))[:,1]
```

Comment: Nice solution! Might fail though, if the axis is in log scale.

Comment: Exactly - for what I'm doing it is working. But maybe there is some more general approach?

Comment: For more general approach you can always tinker with transforms, but it's much more cumbersome and not pythonic. Nevertheless, for the sake of completeness I'm adding it to the answer.