# make axes the same length in matplotlib pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to make square independent from the axis units. I know I can set the figure dimensions equal with `figure(figsize=(10, 10))` for example, and I can set the axis scale ratio equal with `set_aspect('equal')`, but how can I force the actual axis length to be equal, e.g., make xaxis and yaxis each 10 inches long?

**EDIT** Example code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
import numpy as np

x1 = 1
y1 = [10., 1000.]
err1 = 0.00865
x2 = 2
y2 = [9., 900.]
err2 = 0.00658

len_xaxis,len_yaxis = 5.,5. #fix here your numbers
xspace, yspace = .9, .9 # change the size of the void border here.
x_fig,y_fig = len_xaxis / xspace, len_yaxis / yspace

for i in range(2):
    plt.clf()
    #    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(x_fig,y_fig))
    plt.subplots_adjust(left=1-xspace, right = xspace, top=yspace, bottom = 1-yspace)
    gs = gridspec.GridSpec(3, 1)
    gs.update(hspace=0., wspace=0.)
    ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0:2, 0])

    ax1.errorbar(x1, y1[i], yerr=err1)
    ax1.errorbar(x2, y2[i], yerr=err2)

    ax1.invert_yaxis()

    plt.setp(ax1.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)  # Remove x-labels between the plots
    plt.xlim(0, 3)

    ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[2, 0], sharex=ax1)

    nbins = len(ax1.get_yticklabels())
    ax1.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(nbins=8, prune='both'))
    nbins = len(ax2.get_yticklabels())
    ax2.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(nbins=6, prune='both'))

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig('prune_%d.png' % i)
    plt.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Play with the `plt.subplots_adjust()` function. Example for 5 inches instead of 10:

```
len_xaxis,len_yaxis = 5.,5. #fix here your numbers

xspace, yspace = .9, .9 # change the size of the void border here.

x_fig,y_fig = len_xaxis / xspace, len_yaxis / yspace
figure(figsize=(x_fig,y_fig))
plt.subplots_adjust(left=1-xspace, right = xspace, top=yspace, bottom = 1-yspace)
plot([1,2,3],[-1,3,5])
```

Comment: Well, that does not work. Depending on the data (and therefore opn the length of the axis labels) in different plots I get the same hight in all plots but not the same width. The x and y axis don't have a fix inch length ratio.

Comment: I tried your code with the example I postet [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27910125/1812066). Depending on what y-values I use (i.e., how many digits the y tick labels have) the axis length ratio changes, also with your code added.

Comment: This is not an example to work on. I had a look at that code, and the solution worked, the 2 axes (top and bottom) together occupy exactly 5x5 inches. Please edit the question with an example of it failing.

Comment: Thanks, I included an example already with your suggestion in it. You are right, your code works. However, I use plt.tight_layout(), which seems to override the adjustment and I get differing axis length ratios in the two plots. Is there a way to circumvent that?

Comment: Not that i am award of. Basically that command changes the same parameters of plt.subplots_adjust() overriding it

Comment: Ok thanks. Than I will just try to make it work without `tight_layout()`