# Why does matplotlib.ticker.MaxNLocator(prune='both') not prune my tick labels?

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot, pruning

I am trying to make a plot including a number of subplots, and I want them to share their axes. I have been trying to use `matplotlib.ticker.MaxNLocator` to do prune the labels on my ticks, so the figure has readable axes. However, regardless of whether I use `prune='upper'`, `'lower'`, or `'both'`, I end up with labels which overlap each other, as shown in the image below:

[image: subplots]

An ever so slightly simplified version of the code I am using (although still fairly long, sorry) is below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as tck

chains = np.array([[-.4, 4, 0, 0, 0], [6, 19, 2000, 2.1e16, 6.1e13]])
pars   = np.array([r'$SF_\infty$', r'$\tau_D$', r'$\tau$', 'width', 'scale'])
nplots = len(chains[0,:]) - 1

# Fix up matplotlib to give plots like you like
mpl.rcParams.update({'font.size': 6, 'font.family': 'serif', 'mathtext.fontset': 'cm', 'mathtext.rm': 'serif',
    'lines.linewidth': .7, 'xtick.top': True, 'ytick.right': True})

# Make a plot
fig = plt.figure()
for i in range(1,nplots+1):
    for j in range(nplots):
        if (j<i):
            ax = plt.subplot(nplots, nplots, (i-1)*nplots+j+1)
            plt.plot(chains[ :, j ], chains[ :, i ], '.-', markersize=0.3, alpha=0.5)

            # Set aspect
            xlim, ylim = ax.get_xlim(), ax.get_ylim()
            ax.axis([xlim[0], xlim[1], ylim[0], ylim[1]])
            ax.set_aspect( float(xlim[1]-xlim[0]) / (ylim[1]-ylim[0]) )

            # Print things around the edges
            if (j == 0):        plt.ylabel(pars[i])
            if (i == nplots):   plt.xlabel(pars[j])
            if (j != 0):        ax.tick_params(labelleft=False)
            if (i != nplots):   ax.tick_params(labelbottom=False)
            if (j != i-1):
                ax.get_xaxis().get_offset_text().set_visible(False)
                ax.get_yaxis().get_offset_text().set_visible(False)
            # End if-statements

            # Fix tickers
            ax.minorticks_on()
            ax.tick_params(which='both', direction='inout', width=0.5)
            ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(tck.MaxNLocator(nbins=5, prune='both'))
            ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(tck.MaxNLocator(nbins=5, prune='both'))

# Saving file
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0, wspace=-.58)
plt.savefig('testing.png', dpi=400, bbox_inches='tight')
plt.close('all')
```

What am I misunderstanding in my usage of the `MaxNLocator` function? I am using Matplotlib 2.0.0.

(Also obviously, any comments on how to improve this plot for readability and decrease the amount of hard-coding is much appreciated!)

Comment: "prune" only works for the ticks that are at the edge of the plot. Here the outer labels are not at the edge of the plot, so they won't be affected by this option. Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27910125/matplotlib-prune-tick-labels)